# How to make multiple legends the same on a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a graph of 30 categories. Each category consists of about 200 entries.

I would like to make groups of 5 look exactly the same on a graph, so that, for example, categories 1-5 are all represented by a round green dot, categories 6-10 are represented by a round yellow dot, 11-15 are represented by a round red dot, and so on.

How can I achieve this without clicking through 30 different dots and having to manually adjust 6000 entries?

Comment: What kind of chart?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the source data so that all the data for one "colour" are in one series.

[image]